# ASP.NET Button event is not raised in Web User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a ASP.NET user control, which contains a Telerik Report Viewer plus a button (server control).

I need to handle some stuff inside the click event of the button, but the event does not seem to fire.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Here is the HTML directives inside the UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TelerikReportCustomRetrive.UserControl.ReportControl" %>
```

Here is the markup inside the UserControl:

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
<telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="461px" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowHistoryButtons="False" ShowNavigationGroup="False" ShowParametersButton="False" ShowPrintPreviewButton="False"></telerik:ReportViewer>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNav" OnClick="btnNav_Click" />
```

And the code behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var instanceReportSource = new InstanceReportSource
            {
                ReportDocument =
                    new TheReport()
            };
            ReportViewer1.ReportSource = instanceReportSource;
        }
    }



    protected void btnNav_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button Fired!");
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code, both the markup where the button that does not fire is defined and the code-behind (C#) for the button event handler.

Comment: Now.. You have it my friend

Comment: please Provide your HTML code.

Comment: have you used updatePanel in your page?

Comment: And you have put a break point on `btnNav_Click` and verified that it does not get hit by the debugger?

Comment: @Manish Sharma: No I have not

Comment: @Karl: Sure.. But you know the Page_load is fired but the Button Event no.. !!!

Comment: You have a user control in a page and inside that user control another user control with a button which not fires the click event?

Comment: @Alex: No. There is an .aspx page in which I have a User Control and in the User Control there are a 'Telerik Report Viewer' besides a 'Button'.

Comment: @Alex: Actually I am developing an MVC3 app, in which in order to display report viewer I decided to use aspx view engine only for the report pages. Could it be the reason that project is an MVC one?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the telerik control? Do you add any dynamic controls in your code?

Comment: @Patrick: No it doesn't work even when I remove telerik control. And no there isn't any dynamic control added..

Comment: So.. Does it work if you *only* have the button? If it doesn't, perhaps mixing like you stated does not work. Have you read anywhere about how to combine the two?

Comment: Yes.. I think you're right as I made a new web form app and the user control with its child controls worked perfectly.. And Sure I have read and searched for days how to combine aspx and razor.. Almost there are not too much ways for generating the reports in MVC but mizing the two..

Comment: @Patrick: Let me ask you something else please: Does paging in Telerik Report Viewer improves performance of large reports? Do you have any idea? I know this is true about RDLC as I read in MSDN forum..

Comment: What performance would that be, in rendering, or speed, or memory consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the **if(!PostBack)** statement. You should always initialize the control, not only if page is not post back.

Comment: I did that, but nothing happens

Comment: This is not true. Depending on the control, it might keep this in its viewstate.